# Why do I not see a new ruby process when I shell out?

Tags: ruby, process, fork

My understanding is that when you shell out in ruby, the entire ruby process forks first. However, I can't find a way to observe this at the OS level. All I see is the standalone OS process. My methodology is below. In the sleep case I'm expecting to see some sort of ruby child process, but I only see the OS-level sleep process running. As comparison, I also do an explicit fork to see what shows up in the output of ps. The behavior here is what I expect.

Is there something wrong with my methodology (maybe ps isn't showing child processes in some cases?), or am I wrong about ruby forking?

### Terminal 1 (pts/0)

running irb

I try this:

```
`sleep 10`
```

And this:

```
Process.wait2(Process.fork {sleep 10})
```

### Terminal 2 (pts/2)

```
watch "ps -A -O rss |grep 'pts/0'| grep -v 'pts/1'"
```

## Results

### Before

```
3795 10704 S pts/0    00:00:00 irb
```

### After

#### shell sleep

```
3795 10704 S pts/0    00:00:00 irb
4397   680 S pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 5
```

#### ruby fork

```
3795 10704 S pts/0    00:00:00 irb
4449  5680 S pts/0    00:00:00 irb
```

Comment: Isn't there a separate ruby process there? Your "ruby fork" output shows 2 irb processes.

Comment: @maxpleaner yes — that's expected. i'm also expecting to see some sort of ruby process in the shell case. I just updated the question to explain this better. Thanks for asking!

Comment: I am not sure why you would expect to see a ruby process if you shell out. You should expect to see a shell process. After all, you are running a shell command, not a ruby command.

Comment: @JörgWMittag google [ruby backtick fork] and you will see some discussion of the fact that ruby forks whatever process is running before shelling out. I don't know the history of this but digging around in the ruby source does show some language about forking when creating a pipe. I've never seen a great explanation of it though! See the Readme here https://github.com/rtomayko/posix-spawn

Comment: Some good discussion of the whole issue here: https://blog.sundaycoding.com/blog/2014/02/05/fighting-paperclip-errno-enomem-error/

Comment: I would assume that even *if* YARV uses the ancient and obsolete method of `fork` + `exec`, the time window in between the `fork` and the `exec` would be much too small to observe the original process, especially with such crude tools as `ps`. If YARV uses a more modern method such as `posix_spawn`, there won't even be a time window with the original process.